# <h:outputText> is rendered only based on boolean check and its not rendering for String equals check

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a code

```
<h:outputText id="idTxt" value="#{systemBean.checkSize}"
rendered="#{systemBean.vpmoEditFlag == true}">
```

The above code renders correctly in the UI.

but, when I add a condition
 `systemBean.checkSize eq 'Y'`  to the above code which will be

```
 <h:outputText id="idTxt" value="#{systemBean.checkSize}"
 rendered="#{systemBean.vpmoEditFlag == true and systemBean.checkflag eq 'Y'}">
```

is not redering in the UI.

Both the variables

> vpmoEditFlag & checkflag

are ***declared globally in the backing bean which is systemBean***.
I tried "==" for instead of "eq" for the above condition but its does not work.
What might be the problem ? Any help will be really helpful to resolve this issue.

Comment: Show how you have defined the property `checkflag` in `systemBean`

Comment: Looks like `checkflag` value is not `'Y'`.

Comment: If this code is the same of the last question you've made, note that the vpmoEditFlag is always false when checkflag is true. You might need to correct that in your code.

Comment: try adding another outputtext with value="#{systemBean.vpmoEditFlag == true and systemBean.checkflag eq 'Y'}" , which will show the output of your expression. This will let u know what the actual value is

Comment: I am checking the coditions using "and" which means the both condition given above should be satisfied to render the component ,in that case why do i have to change vpmoeditflag  to "true"  for 'y' n "no" for 'n'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure `checkflag` is String datatype. Both `eq` and `==` are valid.
If `checkflag` is String then 'Y' should work.

Check this out http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html for more info.

Comment: User:Thank you so muc!! Will look into the link.

Comment: Glad it could be of any help.